# Postgres 14 won't start

Tags: postgresql

Windows 10 Pro | Postgres 14.

last log:

```
2023-02-13 10:15:04.673 GMT [7956] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-02-13 10:15:04.675 GMT [7956] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-13 10:15:04.679 GMT [8744] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2023-02-13 10:15:04.728 GMT [7956] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 8744) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-13 10:15:04.729 GMT [8700] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-13 10:15:04.884 GMT [7956] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

If I try and start the postgres service in services I get:
"postgres server started then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs"

I did add the computer to a domain via intune and that might have caused these issues (other things have stopped working like my ability to create a restore point).  I have now removed it from that domain.

Answer (score 0):

OK found it
Intune "enforced" bitlocker protection.  Even though bitlocker protection was off it looks like it changed settings such that it prevented write access to non C: drives (my postgres data is not on C:).
I went to local registry to disable bitlocker fixed drive read only.
Then changed permissions back on the drives.

Beware Intune...